# Convert a 2D numpy array into a 3d numpy array representing a grayscaled image

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am using OpenCV with numpy and Python. I have a 2D `uint8` numpy array. The values represent the local densities of over-threshold pixels from a thresholded image. I would like to convert this into a 3-dimensional RGB image with all RGB values set the same, so basically a grayscale image where the maximum value gets `(255,255,255)` and everything else is scaled accordingly. (I need RGB because this seems to be the only kind of image I can write to video with OpenCV).  What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you have a 2D grayscale image, something like:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> img_gray = cv2.imread('./440px-Lenna.png', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE) # image take from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna
```

Now `img_gray` contains a gray scale image:

```
>>> print(img_gray.shape)
 (440, 440)
```

You can convert the image to BGR in an efficient way using `cv2.cvtColor`:

```
>>> img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(img_gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
>>> print(img_bgr.shape)
 (440, 440, 3)
```